# Jquery each: how to send parameters with callback

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$j(".attribute-option-images").each(closeSelectBox(index,el));
```

and then:

```
closeSelectBox = function(index,el)
{
    // stuff
}
```

but all I get is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: index is not defined
```

so how to send the iterated element over to `closeSelectBox`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first line, you call the method `closeSelectBox()`, but you expect to pass it to `each()`.
The signature is matching so all you need to do is to re-write that line to:

```
$j(".attribute-option-images").each(closeSelectBox);
```

Hand over the function, not the return value!

The message "index is not defined" states, that in that first line, index is actually not defined, but it gets defined in the function definition below.

Comment: +1. As the question concludes *how to send the iterated element over to `closeSelectBox`*, one might also point out that this will be accessible as `this` in the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$j(".attribute-option-images").each(function(index, el) { 
     closeSelectBox(index,el) 
});
```

This code `closeSelectBox(index,el)` is executed immediately that why you didn't get index error. Use without parenthesis like

```
$j(".attribute-option-images").each(closeSelectBox);

  function closeSelectBox(index,el){ 

  }
```